# getTabHost() is returning null

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, tabactivity

I am following the directions for a [TabLayout](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tabwidget.html).  Everything is pretty much an exact copy from that page.

```
public class DashboardActivity extends TabActivity {
```

the problem is that in this line `TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();`, tabHost is always null, which causes a null pointer exception in the `TabActivity` base class.

Is there something I am missing?

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    profile = Controller.getProfile();

    this.setContentView(R.layout.test);

    buildTabs();
}

private void buildTabs()
{
    Resources res = getResources(); // Resource object to get Drawables
    TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();// The activity TabHost

    if(tabHost != null)
    {
        // Initialize a TabSpec for each tab and add it to the TabHost
        TabSpec statementSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("statements").setIndicator("Statements (" + profile.Statements.length + ")",
                          res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tabs_statements))
                      .setContent(new Intent().setClass(DashboardActivity.this, SplashActivity.class));
        tabHost.addTab(statementSpec);

        TabSpec paymentSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("payments").setIndicator("Payments (" + profile.Items.length + ")",
                          res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tabs_payments))
                      .setContent(new Intent().setClass(DashboardActivity.this, SplashActivity.class));
        tabHost.addTab(paymentSpec);

        tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
    }
}
```

Layout

```
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:padding="5dp">
        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:padding="5dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

state-list drawable

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- When selected, use grey -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_tab_active"
          android:state_selected="true" />
    <!-- When not selected, use white-->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_tab_suspended" />
</selector>
```

I even tried moving the images in the state-list drawable from /rex/drawable to /res/drawable-hdpi.  I always get the same error.

```
05-31 21:22:23.753: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(647): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-31 21:22:23.753: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(647): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.ftni.consumer/com.ftni.consumer.ui.DashboardActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-31 21:22:23.753: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(647):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1622)
05-31 21:22:23.753: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(647):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1638)
05-31 21:22:23.753: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(647):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
05-31 21:22:23.753: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(647):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:928)
05-31 21:22:23.753: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(647):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-31 21:22:23.753: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(647):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
05-31 21:22:23.753: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(647):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3647)
05-31 21:22:23.753: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(647):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-31 21:22:23.753: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(647):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
05-31 21:22:23.753: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(647):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
05-31 21:22:23.753: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(647):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
05-31 21:22:23.753: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(647):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-31 21:22:23.753: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(647): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-31 21:22:23.753: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(647):     at android.app.TabActivity.onPostCreate(TabActivity.java:79)
05-31 21:22:23.753: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(647):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnPostCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108)
05-31 21:22:23.753: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(647):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1605)
```

Has anyone else had problems implementing the standard tab activity?  Any pointers on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried putting all of the code for the buildTabs() method in your onCreate() method? Let me know if that fixes it.

Comment: The exception is in class TabActivity and not your class. This tells me something else is wrong with your app. Have you tried rolling back to what used to work from the that link until seeing what breaks?

Comment: Vinay, I moved the code into the oncreate and now it works.  I'm not sure why it doesn't work to put in a method that is called from the same spot in `onCreate`.  If you post an answer, I will mark it correct.

Comment: Glad it helped man. I actually had a ton of problems with this kind of "context" passing between different methods. Honestly the easiest way is to just avoid referring to your activity's resources outside of your onCreate() method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try putting all of the code for buildTabs() in your onCreate() method.

Answer (score 0):

Write

```
tabHost.setup();
```

instead of:

```
 tabHost = getTabHost();
```

This should solve the problem.